# painting the plane

Tags: geometry

If the plane has been colored so that each point has one of three colors (Red,Blue,Yellow).

Prove that for any interval AB there exists two points of the same color with $AB \cong CD $

This is a problem from Hartshore a translation of Euclid 
EX 5.18

Anyone have any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following [unit graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph), the [Moser spindle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoserSpindle.html), which has common distance between points as shown by the edges.

[image]

This requires four colours to have different colours on adjacent vertices. As you have specified only three colours, any example of this figure would have two points at the required distance having the same colour.

Comment: For comparison with lulu's answer, imagine the top point is the origin, so the lower two points are on the specified $\sqrt 3 L $ circle. Then either one of the diamonds is the construction for case 2.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the origin, $O$,  is red.  Construct the circle , $C$ centered at $O$ of radius $\sqrt 3\, L$ where $L$ is the length of $AB$.

Case I:  Every point on $C$ is red (this case is trivial as $C$ clearly admits chords of length $L$).

Case II.  At least one point on $C$ is not red, let's say the point $P$ is Blue.  In this case construct the segment $XY$ such that the triangles $\Delta OXY$, $\Delta PXY$ are both equilateral of side length $L$.  If $X,Y$ are both yellow, we are done.  Otherwise one of them is either red or blue and again we are done.